# Cypher can't take all properties from CSV

Tags: csv, cypher

I try to create relations from a CSV, but I've got an error

```
Cannot merge the following relationship because of null property 
value for 'timestamp': (u)-[:WATCHED {timestamp: null}]->(m)
```

I don't understand, the CSV doesn't miss any property

My code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmtjxr22q4fflr1/u.data.csv?dl=1' AS line 
FIELDTERMINATOR '|' MATCH(u:User{id:toInteger(line.id_user)}), 
(m:Movie{id:toInteger(line.id_item)}) WITH u,m, line MERGE (u)- 
[r:WATCHED{rating:toInteger(line.rating), 
timestamp:toInteger(line.timestamp)}]->(m)
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded your CSV. Its header is the following:

```
id_user|id_item|rating|timestamp
```

Note that *it has an extra space character at the end of the line*. This causes the property to be called `timestamp` , therefore, `timestamp` will be `null`.

Comment: you're right my bad....
I want now convert timestamp in date like this : date:datetime(toInteger(line[3]))
but i've this error: Invalid call signature for DateTimeFunction: Provided input was [Long(881250949)]
Could you help me ?

Comment: The syntax is `datetime{epochseconds: ...}`. If you are not using the header, you should also throw away the first line using `WITH line SKIP 1`. So the query is the following: `LOAD CSV FROM '...' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|' WITH line SKIP 1 RETURN datetime({epochseconds: toLong(line[3])})`.

If the answer helped you, please accept & upvote it.